# Why binding.myTextView returns a TextView? and not TextView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-viewbinding, kotlin-null-safety

In my layout that is called `activity_main.xml`, I have two TextView. I can access it from my MainActivity by using a variable

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

in this way:

```
binding.textView1
binding.textView2
```

In my code `binding.textView1` returns an object `TextView` but the second returns an object `TextView?`.

That forces me to access the second TextView with `?.` operator like

```
binding.textView2?.text = "HelloWorld"
```

because using the `.` operator cause the error

```
Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type TextView?
```

So the questions are there a method for defining a View not nullable in my layout? How is possible that two objects with the same property had different behavior?

Comment: Maybe post your activity_main.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object was nullable because it was present not in all XML layouts, so in some layouts it was null.